# More than a few conditions

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

is there any easy way to write more conditions into my python scripts without writing if/else parts?

Let set like 30 conditions I want program to check and then do various things depends on those conditions.

I mean, I don't want to make something like this:

if X:

elif Y:

elif Z:

elif:

May I use dictionary for that or any other structure?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Maybe you can use a dict, depends on the actual, specific use case.

Comment: I mean, I want to check every single move I can do in this program, and then program has to do special thing depends on  every possible scenario. Like chess game.

Comment: Python 3.10 introduced a [match-case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/) statement which *might* be more readable then an if ... elif cascade.

Comment: Stop being unspecific and broad.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way by using a function dictionary.

Here is an example.

```
def funA():
    print("This is fun")

def funB():
    print("This is also fun")

def funC():
    print("Okay this is not fun anymore")

def funD():
    print("Why am I even here")

def main():
    func = {
    "Condition A": funA,
    "Condition B": funB,
    "Condition C": funC,
    "Condition D": funD,
    }
    while True:
        try:
            func[input("Input a condition: ")]()
        except KeyError:
            print("Bad choice, please type one of these:")
            for key in func:
                print(key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```